# Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to execute a curl command in powershell:

```
curl --user bitcoinipvision --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "move", "params": ["acc-1", "acc-2", 6, 5, "happy birthday!"] }' -H 'content-type: application/json;' http://localhost:18332/
```

But I get this error, what is the problem?

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the
"content-type: application/json;" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:158
+ ... 5, "happy birthday!"] }' -H 'content-type: application/json;' http:// ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Try `alias curl`, it apparently goes to `Invoke-WebRequest` (not on my PowerShell though). If you want the real `curl`, explicitly use `curl.exe`.

Comment: you have mentioned the content as application/json whereas you are passing it as string. If its proper json then use convertto-json to get it converted to json

Comment: Note that recent versions of PowerShell have [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) and full support for JSON (`ConvertTo-Json` and the like). It's worth reading up on native PowerShell ways to do this.

Comment: These [Invoke-RestMethod examples](https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/invoke-restmethod-powershell-examples/) will help as I didn't find the documentation great.

Answer (score 59):

As already stated out by some commenters you will see that `curl` is actually just an alias to [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1):

```
PS> Get-Command curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

*Note: I suggest to use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-Command?view=powershell-5.1), not [`Get-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-5.1) because you maybe don't know if the command you are using is an alias, cmdlet, or an executable.*

**From this point there are two possible ways to solve your issue:**

1. Use PowerShell's [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1) (or, if you are using PowerShell < 3, [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)):

   ```
   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost:18332/ -Credential bitcoinipvision -body $thisCanBeAPowerShellObject
   ```

   As you can see, no content-type is needed as JSON is IRM's default content Type; though you can change it using `-ContentType`.
2. If available in your current environment, use the original [`cUrl`](https://curl.haxx.se/). You have to type it this way:

   ```
   curl.exe --user bitcoinipvision --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "move", "params": ["acc-1", "acc-2", 6, 5, "happy birthday!"] }' -H 'content-type: application/json;' http://localhost:18332/
   ```

I would definitely prefer the first one over the 2nd one, as PowerShell natively supports JSON answers, which allows you to easily use them, e.g. by piping it to `Where-Object`, `Format-Table`, `Select-Object`, `Measure-Object` and so much mure. If you prefer to use cUrl, you have to parse the String returned by the `curl.exe` process on your own. This could also be problematic with binary content.

Comment: curl.exe on Powershell 

Answer (score 16):

Curl basically uses Invoke-Webrequest in PowerShell.

As you can see in the error, the header basically accepts the form "System.Collections.IDictionary"n and you are passing through a "System.String".

Converting the Header to a dictionary/hashtable would resolve the issue,

```
curl --user bitcoinipvision --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "move", "params": ["acc-1", "acc-2", 6, 5, "happy birthday!"] }' -H @{ "content-type" = "application/json"} http://localhost:18332/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, until i found this: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31851

"The commands are designed to be ran within the specific VM and in a Bash environment. Not in PowerShell. So the error you see would be expected in most cases."

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while using visual studio code terminal, and I solved it by using the cmd

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).