# How to make a curl request with body to local server

Tags: node.js, curl, post

I have NodeJS code which looks like this

```
app.post("/calc", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true, 
        msg: req.body.msg,
    })
})
```

I can't use Postman that's why I want to test this endpoint using curl. How to do this?

I tried code like this but it returned an error

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/calc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"msg": 123456}'
```

Error:

```
 Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/json" value of type "System.String" to type "S
ystem.Collections.IDictionary".
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183355/invoke-webrequest-cannot-bind-parameter-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were missing this code on your `express` side.

Because Postman did not work either.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

#### Demo code, save as `server.js` file

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors())

// for form-data of Body
const multer = require('multer');
const forms = multer();
app.use(forms.array()); 

// for x-www-form-urlencoded of Body
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// for raw JSON of Body
app.use(express.json()); 

app.post('/calc', (req, res)=> {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true, 
        msg: req.body.msg,
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log("Listening on : 3000") })
```

#### Install dependencies

```
npm install express cors multer
```

#### Run it by node

```
node server.js
```

#### Test if by curl

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/calc' \
--silent \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "msg": 123456
}'
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Test by Postman

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Windows tricks you up so that you use the curl Invoke-webrequest alias instead of the *real* curl tool.

Try invoking curl as `curl.exe` to avoid that nastiness.

Also: drop `-X POST` from that command line, `-d` already means POST.